# React conditional tag name not working - all letters downsized

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render tag name based on prop value.
Example

```
   const SimpleTagName = `Ball${size === 'large' ? 'Large' : 'Small'}`;

   return (<SimpleTagName />
```

but the problem is that I get rendered 'balllarge' tag with all lower case letters. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
    photo: PhotoStory,
    video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
    // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
    const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
    return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

Official doc ref to handle this pattern: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

JSX gets converted to a `React.createElement()` call, so what you're doing effectively turns into:

```
React.createElement('balllarge')
```

Which is not what you want. You need to pass it an component instead of a string, but you can still determine that dynamically, like so:

```
import { BallLarge, BallSmall } from './Balls' // or whatever

const Component = ({ size }) => {
  const BallComponent = size === 'large' ? BallLarge : BallSmall

  return <BallComponent />
}
```

(If you have more than two options, you may need a different way to handle the mapping between your props and variable types, but the principle remains the same: assign a component to a variable, and then use when rendering.)